# Timer to a given event

Tags: c#

I'm trying to make a shutdown timer. Meaning a start a timer of a given time, and set the computer to shutdown after that. I've searched the internet + stackoverflow of cause, and i can't find anything useful to use both to time my own shutdown event and showing it on the screen.

Comment: you can do a .NET Forms Application. Put a Timer Control on page. Display the Counter on page with label control, counting down descending. Then once completed. Call a Shutdown command with Shell, or internally with WMI or Process.Start("shutdown","/s /t 0");

Comment: You want the *computer* to shut down when your application timer expires? re: your comment in the answer below, a timer has no on-screen presence. If you want to see the timer count down, you need to create your own display component for it. Edit your question and give us more information about what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

What have you tried?

If you want the timer to remain active when your program ends, I recommend using the task planer. You can define the execution time, set it to execute exactly once and to be deleted afterwards. ( http://www.thewindowsclub.com/schedule-shutdown-restarts-windows-7-task-schedular )

Otherwise, you may create a timer inside you application and bind an appropriate event to it.

You need administrator privilege for both.

---

To display the time, you need something on your Form to display it on. For example a label. Then you can do as follows:

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var x = new Timer();
        x.Tick += new EventHandler((obj, eventargs) => {
            var t = obj as Timer;
            var tag = (int)t.Tag;

            label1.Text = string.Format("{0:0.0}s until shutdown", tag/10d);
            t.Tag = tag - 1;

            if (tag == 0)
            {
                t.Enabled = false;
                MessageBox.Show("I shall initiate the shutdown here!", "Brace yourself!");
                Process.Start("shutdown", "/s /t 10"); // Do the actual shutdown here
            }

        });
        x.Interval = 100;
        x.Tag = 30;
        x.Enabled = true;
    }
```

If you want to abort the countdown you want to promote the local variable to a private field of the form. That way you can disable the timer at any time.

Comment: I don't want the timer to be active after the program gets closed. And i want to manage the timers myself. I've tried system.timers.timer, system.threading.timers, and a third. I can't get it to display on screen.